# Laravel 419 error using Uppy open source, how to add csrf token to Uppy?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Before some of you mark this as duplicate since error 419 using laravel has been answered a million times, this is a bit more complicated and I cant seem to work around it.

I am trying to use `Uppy` to upload some images however I cant seem to find a way to add the csrf token to Uppy. (https://uppy.io/docs/tus/#headers)

```
const uppy = Uppy();
uppy.use(Dashboard, { target: '#drag-drop-area', inline: true, height: 450 });
uppy.use(Tus, {
     header: 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'+document.querySelector('[name=csrf-token]').getAttribute('content'),
     endpoint: 'https://mysitev/tus', // use your tus endpoint here
     resume: true,
     autoRetry: true,
     retryDelays: [0, 1000, 3000, 5000]
})
```

Does anyone has used Uppy in the past and if so how did you include the csrf_token?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not used Uppy, but if your code is in your view file, it means the files which have blade extensions can use blade functions to add a csrf token:

```
headers: {
        'X-CSRFToken': " {{csrf_token()}} "
    }
```

Comment: that did work. I cant believe i didnt thought of just using a blade extension before ¬¬ thank you

Comment:  u can write ur js in views and can include using push('scripts')

Answer (score 2):

Try with it:

```
uppy.use(Uppy.Tus, {
    endpoint: '{{ $endpoint }}',
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-Token': " {{ csrf_token() }} "
    }
})
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Webpack or have your Uppy configuration bundled with other JavaScript files you can assign your token to a meta tag and use it in JS later

In your blade.php

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Then in your Uppy.js

```
.use(Tus, {
endpoint: '/tus', // use your tus endpoint here
retryDelays: [0, 1000, 3000, 5000],
headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
}
```

})